# MySQL: find out what date a row was added to a table?

Tags: mysql

I added a new column to a table called price_request_date because I now need to track the date each one was made. I made it so new ones enter the current date when they insert a new row. I was just wondering if there was any way to fill in the previous rows with the dates they were entered? I don't know if MySQL keeps track of that sort of thing or not, but worth an ask. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is not. There is no way to automatically backdate a timestamp field with the original creation date if it weren't already set at creation time.

Frustrating - I know.

Answer (score 1):

nope.  it is good to always include LastChgID and LastChgDate on tables like this, do that next time from the get go...